# My page wont scroll down?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this page but as soon as the screen is smaller it wont make me scroll down to see more of my text.
Here is the link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDv5u/)

```
 <html>
 <div class="container_12 container clearfix">

        <div class="grid_12 clearfix main_content">
            <div class="content">
                <div><img src="http://placehold.it/780x150"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>title</h1> 
                    <p> text<p>
                    <p> text<p>
                    <p> text<p>
                    <p> text<p>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div>
 </html>

 <style>

 .content{
     width: 780px;
     padding: 20px;
     position: fixed;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     color: #000000;
     font-family: Lora BoldItalic, Lora;
     margin-top: -312px;
     margin-left: -390px;
  }
 .text {
     background: gray;
     opacity: 0.6;
     padding: 20px;
 }
 </style>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please include some code, and more of an explanation of what you have tried, in the question. JSFiddle is a brilliant way to test and demonstrate issues, but it shouldn't be an alternative to a good question.

Comment: *"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."* You saw this message, don't you?

Comment: Sorry about that, It's my first time over here. I edited my question And should be properly added by now hopefully.

Comment: Change `position:fixed;` to other e.g.: **absolute** and relative if possible after looking your code at instance. Your `top:50%;` may also cause to stop scroll.

Comment: Is this your actual HTML? If so.. it is invalid (no `doctype` no `head` or `body` tags and `style` should not be outside `html` tag.

Comment: Not really, i just added the significant information just to show specifically what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed a few things from your CSS:

```
    position: fixed; 
    left: 50%; 
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -312px; 
    margin-left: -390px;
```

In general (unless you really know what are you doing) using margin (especially negative values), position fixed, left and top is a bad idea because you are forcing elements to stay in a fixed position so your page will not work in all screen sizes.

I saw in your code that you are trying something with a background (is not visible in the demo) try to add the background to `body` not to `html`. I don't know what you are trying but I have a feeling that you want the page content to scroll without moving the background you will need to check this out http://jsfiddle.net/gF7Af/31/

I have the following:

```
.myimg{
    margin: auto;
}

.content{
    margin: auto;
    width: 780px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Lora BoldItalic, Lora;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer its been really helpful!, although I also wanted a white box in the middle of my page with some text on it, but the position:fixed makes my page not scroll down, do you have any suggestion for that? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you soo much! It really cleared up my mistake, I was fixing the main container and I it wasn't scrolling down, I really appreciate it mate :-)

Comment: Glad to help If you solved the issue you should flag the answer as valid so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

i dont see any of your text.. i dont understand why you put fixed position to the content nor those negative margins, so i removed those odd rules and at least i can see the text now.

Modify **.content** like this:

```
.content{
    width: 780px;
    padding: 20px;
    /*margin: auto;*/
    color: #000;
    font-family: Lora BoldItalic, Lora;
}
```

Comment: The margins and position settings are likely for having the content centered both horizontally and vertically on the screen.

Comment: It could be but theres a lot of better ways to center content, why to use fixed position like that..

Comment: I can think of two possible reasons: 1. It is a rather simple approach and 2. There are tutorials that use this approach.